# Retrieve internal/canonical representation of terms in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am writing a program for which I need terms in their prefix notation.
The point is to being able to parse mathematical expressions to prefix notation, while preserving the correct order of Operations. I then want to save the result in the database for later use (using assert), which includes translating to another language, which uses prefix notation. Prolog Operators do all have a fixed priority which is a feature I want to use, as I will be using all sorts of operators (including clp operators).

As among others I need to include complete mathematical expressions, such as the equality operator. Thus I cannot recursively use the Univ operator (=..), because it won't accept equality operators etc. Or can I somehow use =.. ?

Essentially I want to work with the internal representation of

```
N is 3*4+5   % just a random example
```

which would be

```
is(N,+(*(3,4),5))
```

Now, I do know that I can use, `write_canonical(N is 3*4+5)` to get the internal representation as seen above.

So is there a way to somehow get the internal representation as a term or a list, or something.
Would it be possible to bind the output of write_canonical to a variable?

I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: As Paulo says - alternatively, you can directly use "univ" [`=..`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D..)/2) and friends (there are a few edge cases where `=..` fails, at least in SWI-Prolog, thus the friends). Pump the structure into a list: `(N is 3*4+5) =.. L.` gives `L = [is, N, 3*4+5]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prolog terms can be despicted as *trees*. But, when writing a term, the way a term is *displayed* depends on the defined operators and write options. Consider:

```
?- (N is 3*4+5) = is(N,+(*(3,4),5)).
true.

?- (N is 3*4+5) = is(Variable, Expression).
N = Variable,
Expression = 3*4+5.

?- 3*4+5 = +(*(3,4),5).
true.
```

I.e. operators are syntactic sugar. They don't change how terms are represented, only how terms are *displayed*.

Comment: Thank you and @DavidTonhofer very much for your help with my basic approach. I did not know using `=..` with extra brackets would do the trick. So now I can actually use the recursive approach with mostly `=..`. So again, thank you guys!